# Spring Data Mongodb - Using @DocumentReference and @Filed at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use *@DocumentReference* together with basic *@Field* annotation as two properties pointing to the same the attribute (in mongoDB) in order to easily manipulate with it. To achieve this I wrote custom lookup but the problem is, that *#self* within SpEL is null I am getting an error:

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'project_id' cannot be found on null**

Code:

```
public record ProjectUser(@Id UUID id,
                      @Field("contact_email") String contactEmail,
                      @Field("phone") String phone,
                      @Field("company") String company,
                      @Field("job_title") String jobTitle,
                      @Field("note") String note,
                      @Field("parent_id") UUID parentId,
                      @Field("user_id") UUID userId,
                      @Field("project_id") UUID projectId,
                      @ReadOnlyProperty @DocumentReference(lookup = "{ '_id' : '?#{#self.project_id}' }") Project project,
                      @Field("project_role_id") UUID roleId,
                      @Field("project_group_ids") List<UUID> projectGroupIds,
                      @Field("deleted") Boolean deleted,
                      @Field("created_date") @CreatedDate OffsetDateTime createdDate,
                      @Field("updated_date") @LastModifiedDate OffsetDateTime updatedDate) {

}
```

Is there a way how to use both *@ReadOnlyProperty @DocumentReference(...) Project project* and *@Field("project_id") UUID projectId* at the same time? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with kotlin, I think it's related to how spring data initializes references, in my case

not working:

```
@Document("test")
data class Test(
  @Id
  val id: ObjectId? = null,
  val name: String,
  @CreatedDate
  val createdAt: Instant = Instant.MIN,
  @CreatedBy
  val createdById: ObjectId = ObjectId(),
  @ReadOnlyProperty
  @DocumentReference(lookup = "{ '_id' : ?#{#self.createdById} }")
  val createdBy: User? = null
)
```

working:

```
@Document("test")
data class Test(
  @Id
  val id: ObjectId? = null,
  val name: String,
  @CreatedDate
  val createdAt: Instant = Instant.MIN,
  @CreatedBy
  val createdById: ObjectId = ObjectId(),      
) {
  @ReadOnlyProperty
  @DocumentReference(lookup = "{ '_id' : ?#{#self.createdById} }")
  var createdBy: User? = null
}
```

you can probably try with regular java class instead of record.

Comment: Hi Slava I have tried your suggestion but upon logging out all the queries my app didn't query for the DocumentReference. Do I have to setup something to use DocumentReference annotation?